# third party module controller overriding not working in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mindtwo_Formbuildercrfprotection>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <depends>
                <Phxsolution_Formbuilder/>
            </depends>
        </Mindtwo_Formbuildercrfprotection>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <formbuilder>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mindtwo_formbuildercrfprotection before="Phxsolution_Formbuilder">Mindtwo_Formbuildercrfprotection</mindtwo_formbuildercrfprotection>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </formbuilder>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and in indexController.php

```
<?php
require_once("Phxsolution/Formbuilder/controllers/IndexController.php");
class Mindtwo_Formbuildercrfprotection_IndexController extends Phxsolution_Formbuilder_IndexController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {die("dsfdf");
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Formbuilder"));

        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Home"),
            "title" => $this->__("Home"),
            "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
        ));
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("formbuilder", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Formbuilder"),
            "title" => $this->__("Formbuilder")
        ));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

- Is `<formbuilder>` the right tag of Phxsolution_Formbuilder module for his controller ? Check his config (`Phxsolution_Formbuilder/etc/config.xml` and see the correct tag)
- Try to use the depends in the etc/modules directory when your module is declared, don't put it in the config.xml.
- Add this :

> require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Phxsolution_Formbuilder').DS.
>   'IndexController.php');

instead of this

> require_once("Phxsolution/Formbuilder/controllers/IndexController.php");

- Try not to use long names for your module (**Formbuildercrfprotection**)

Comment: yes i have checked it tag is correct and i moved depends in etc/modules but still its not working

Comment: Try the require once i posted , also add the die in other positions , add it outside the function to see the result.

Comment: yes i have used require once as you written not working